# Sram quick link on a Shimano chain

Tags: chain, master-link

Is it compatible to use a Sram quick link on a Shimano chain (both 11sp.)?

Comment: They like to keep you confused about this.  Hard to say in any given case.

Comment: I've used 10-speed SRAM quick links on Shimano 10-speed chains.  They work.  And despite SRAM's statements to the contrary, they still work just fine if you reuse them.  You do not have to buy another one just because you used it, then unlinked it to remove your chain for cleaning, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Sram's chains are little bit wider than Shimano's. Sram links will only work with Sram chains. KMC will work with Shimano chains.

Answer (score 1):

They are not supposed to be compatible. Shimano makes a quick link for their chains now so there is not much point in mixing brands.

Comment: Well, I already posess the SRAM links!